# Flutter arguments for Java to process

Tags: java, flutter, dart

Is there way to create in flutter method with argument and pass this argument to Java?
I have code something like this:

**Code in flutter:**

```
  String returnName(String dbName) {
    final String result = platform.invokeMethod("test");
    return result;
  }
```

But there is issue with result variable. It says `A value of type 'Future<dynamic>' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'String'`.
Do someone have tip how I can solve this?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `platform.invokeMethod("test")` is a Future which means it will take time for it to retrieve the data.
So you'll have to use the async/await

```
Future<String> returnName(String dbName) async {
  return = await platform.invokeMethod("test");
}
```

And to call it..

```
...
FutureBuilder(
  future: returnName(),
  builder: (context, snapshot) {
    if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting)
      return CircularProgressIndicator();
    return Text(snapshot.data);
  },
);
```

Comment: Doesn't work, same error. `The argument type 'Future<String>' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'String'.`
I need to call it in `Text();` widget

Comment: @RitchyCZE i have updated my comment.. You will then have to use the `FutureBuilder`